# centering CSS: margin-left and -right auto, but funny results

Tags: css, centering

<strike>You can view the page at http://led.dlugosz.com/.</strike><sup>※</sup>  I want to make the "Gallery" section centered in the available space, not flush left.

So, I added rules

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

and it *seemed* to work just right.  But, when I did the same thing on another page, it didn't work at all, and I can't find any difference.  Then, playing around with this page some more, I find that at different window widths it works, doesn't work, or does something very odd.  What's going on here?  More to the point, how can I accomplish this effect?

---

※ I updated the page and eventually removed it.

Answer (score 6):

`margin-left :auto` and `margin-right:auto` will center the element if you set `display: block` and specify the width of the element then the element align to center.

or else

```
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100px;
display: block;
```

Comment: In earlier answers, you would see that I don’t want to pin the actual width of the element.

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead,

```
.wrap {width: 980px; margin: 0 auto;}
```

Where div class="wrap" would be what you want to center.

Comment: I really don't want to pin the actual width of the element, and I don't see why putting the auto margin in a separate "class" would make any difference.  Maybe you are just sharing your idiom, rather than figuring out why my current use of the same technique is doing funny things?

Answer (score 3):

margin auto has worked for me in all cases with fixed width otherwise use

http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Answer (score 2):

- On `#main_col`, add `margin-right: 20.5em` - this is the same `width` (`18em`) as your right sidebar, plus a little more for margin.
- On `#main_col h2`, remove the `margin-right` property.
- On `#main_col div > *`, remove the `margin-right` property.
- On `#galleries ul`, remove the `margin-left` and `margin-right` properties, and add `display: inline-block`.
- On `#galleries`, add `text-align: center`.
- On `#main_col h2` and `#galleries ul li`, add `text-align: left`.

Tested in Firefox only.

Comment: Adding the margin to #main_col is especially important, because right now you're resorting to adding right-margin/padding to all of your content. It's much, much easier if you add the margins and padding to the container element rather than each piece of content.

Comment: Adding the margin-right on #main_col will give me a straight column.  I want to image buttons to flow around the side bar once it is cleared.

Maybe that very thing is what confuses the browser's layout?  Your other suggestion, of centering the inline content within the ul rather than the ul itself, did the trick.  Odd rows are different, but that's fine.

Comment: Are you sure you want the `"image buttons to flow around the side bar once it is cleared"` - your live site looks like this when it does that: [http://i.imgur.com/EyZfl.jpg](http://i.imgur.com/EyZfl.jpg) (not great) - but if you're sure that's what you want, then it's otherwise fine. If I solved your problem, please [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use Firebug on the other page to be certain that the margin-left and margin-right properties were assigned to that element?  They may have been overridden by a CSS rule with higher priority.

Comment: Yes I checked the actual layout in Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that "margin-left:auto;" and "margin-right:auto;" values only work on block elements. If you want to center inline elements you should use "text-align:center;".